# Given an array, you have to find the max possible two equal sum

Tags: algorithm

Given an array, you have to find the max possible two equal sum, you can exclude elements.

i.e `1,2,3,4,6` is given array
we can have max two equal sum as 6+2 = 4+3+1

i.e 4,10,18, 22,
we can get two equal sum as 18+4 =  22

what would be your approach to solve this problem apart from brute force to find all computation and checking two possible equal sum?

edit 1: max no of array elements are N <= 50 and each element can be up to 1<= K <=1000

edit 2: Here is my solution https://ideone.com/cAbe4g, it takes too much time where given time limit is 5 seconds say for each case.

edit 3:- Total elements sum cannot be greater than 1000.

Comment: There is no limit on how many numbers can be on either side of the equation as long as they're not repeating yes?

Comment: yes, once a number is used at one side, it cannot be added the other side.

Comment: This is a harder version of [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: This reminds me of the "subset sum" problem which is NP complete (runs in non polynomial time) where you have an array of numbers and have to decide if there exists a sum of elements so that the result is = 0. In theory you could replace 0 with any value, however, since you don't know that value either I'd say its a harder variant of the subset sum problem

Comment: I feel this like the subset problem itself, but yes, maybe you need to use a map. I mean if a sum gets visited again. In a map, you insert sum as key against the location of the 2-D array as it's value. So, now if you revisit any sum again, then maybe you can backtrace both sums to see if there are any common elements. If not, then this sum is one possible option and you can take max of all these possible options.

Comment: @vivek_23 the thing is that there are so many different ways to combine the elements in the array, it's not trivial to calculate but it seems to me that it grows as fast as factorial. That's why even with a very small array a brute-force solution can fail. That's a tough problem!

Comment: @Atiq where does the problem come from? Are we sure that there's a polynomial answer out there? I prefer not investing too much time if there isn't ^^

Comment: @Atiq See the editorial. Like Dici mentioned, brute force seems the only way for now. I am not sure if this comes under Advanced DP.

Comment: @vivek_23 intuitively, the reason why the elements are limited to 1000 is to be able to allocate an array of size `k*k = 1 million`, hence dynamic programming. I think there must be a smart DP algorithm for this, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Dici technically, elements are limited to `50`. `1000` is the domain range for each element. So, size will be max `50 * 50 = 2500`.  I too feel there must be a smart DP, but I can't get a hang of it since I am just slightly better than a newbie in it.

Comment: @Dici It comes from programming test, I am not sure about the polynomial solution or it will work with optimization on the exponential solution. I tried but it's taking more time.

Comment: @Atiq yeah but does it come from a website like Hackerrank, or did you just get it from outside (in class, in an interview, in a book etc)?

Comment: @Dici it comes from Samsung R&D center programming competency test. This is the first step of the interview.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Recommended approach

I suggest solving this using DP where instead of tracking A,B (the size of the two sets), you instead track A+B,A-B (the sum and difference of the two sets).

Then for each element in the array, try adding it to A, or B, or neither.

The advantage of tracking the sum/difference is that you only need to keep track of a single value for each difference, namely the **largest** value of the sum you have seen for this difference.

For added efficiency, I recommend you iterate through the elements in order from smallest to largest and stop updating the DP once the largest difference seen so far is reached.

You can also only store the absolute value of the difference, and ignore any difference greater than 25000 (as it will be impossible for the difference to return to 0 from this point).

### Python example code

```
from collections import defaultdict

def max_equal_sum(E):
    D=defaultdict(int)            # Map from abs difference to largest sum
    D[0]=0                        # Start with a sum and difference of 0
    for a in E:                   # Iterate over each element in the array
        D2=D.copy()               # Can keep current sum and diff if element is skipped
        for d,s in D.items():     # d is difference, s is sum
            s2 = s+a              # s2 is new sum
            for d2 in [d-a,d+a]:  # d2 is new difference
                D2[abs(d2)] = max(D2[abs(d2)],s2) # Update with largest sum
        D=D2
    return D[0]/2                 # Answer is half the sum of A+B for a difference of 0

print max_equal_sum([1,2,3,4,6])  # Prints 8
print max_equal_sum([4,10,18,22]) # Prints 22
```

Comment: Mmm sounds interesting but not sure I understand your suggestion. Could you write it in pseudo-code?

Comment: Neat, will take a look

Comment: Nice solution. The copy sounds expensive though. How big can `D` become? Is that really necessary?

Comment: @Dici D can have at most N.K values and needs to be copied N times.  For the parameters of this problem this results in 50 copies of a length 50k dictionary.  I would estimate the worst case is something like: `max_equal_sum(range(1000-50,1000))` which takes 0.5 seconds in Python.

Comment: This answer is being discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270073/clarification-of-answer-find-the-max-possible-two-equal-sum-in-a-set

Comment: Cool. But what if I want to see two arrays that are answer?
For example, if [1,2,3,4,6] is given, this returns 8 which is sum of subarray.
But I want to see [6, 2], [4, 3, 1] as a result.
Does this make this question whole different question or do we just need slight little changes in the above code?

Comment: @JunhoLee You could keep the previous values of D (instead of overwriting with D=D2).  This would then give you enough information to write a loop that backtracked through the arrays starting with a difference of 0 until you reached the start.  (At each step you just need to try the d-a,d+a,d candidates to see which you should select to continue the backtracking.)

Answer (score 2):

The largest set with values from 0 to 1000 which has no two subsets with equal sum has 9 elements, e.g.:

```
{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512}
```

If you add a tenth element, then it will be equal to the sum of a subset of the nine previous values.

If you find two subsets with equal sum after you have excluded more than 9 elements, then two equal sums from the excluded elements can be added to form greater equal sums; this means that you should never exclude more than 9 elements.

The sum of the excluded elements in in the range 0 to 1000. Building a sieve to check which values in this range can be formed with the elements in the set will take at most 50 × 1000 steps. (We can store the minimum number of values that add up to each sum instead of a boolean, and use that to include only sums which can be made with 9 or fewer elements.)

If we then look at the sums of excluded numbers from small to large, that means looking at the sums of included numbers from large to small. For each sum of excluded values, we check which (up to 9) elements can form this sum (obviously not a trivial step, but we know the number of elements is between the minimum value as stored in the sieve, and 9), and this gives us the set of excluded and therefor also the set of included numbers. Then we use a similar sieve technique to check whether the included numbers can form the half sum; this will be in the range 1 to 500 and take at most 50 × 500 steps.

In all this, there is of course the odd/even-ness to take into account: if the total sum is odd, a subset with an odd sum has to be excluded; if the total sum is even, only subsets with an even sum have to be excluded.

I haven't really figured out how to generate worst-case input for this, so it's hard to judge the worst-case complexity; but I think the average case should be feasible.

---

Here are some of the parts in action. First, the sieve to find the sums of the sets of up to 9 values which can be excluded (and have the right odd/even-ness) tested with 20 values with a sum of 999:

```js
function excludedSums(values) {
    var sieve = [0];
    for (var i in values) {
        var temp = [];
        for (var j in sieve) {
            if (sieve[j] == 9) continue;
            var val = values[i] + Number(j);
            if (!sieve[val] || sieve[j] + 1 < sieve[val]) {
                temp[val] = sieve[j] + 1;
            }
        }
        for (var j in temp) {
            sieve[j] = temp[j];
        }
    }
    var odd = values.reduce(function(ac, el) {return ac + el}, 0) % 2;
    for (var i in sieve) {
        if (Number(i) % 2 != odd) delete sieve[i];
    }
    return sieve;
}
var set = [40,7,112,15,96,25,49,49,31,87,39,8,79,40,73,49,63,55,12,70];
var result = excludedSums(set);
for (var i in result) document.write(i + ", ");
```

Next, the sets of up to 9 values with a certain sum. In the example above, we see that e.g. one or more sets with the sum 99 can be excluded; let's find out what these sets are:

```js
function excludedSets(values, target) {
    var sieve = [[[]]];
    for (var i in values) {
        var temp = [];
        for (var j in sieve) {
            var val = values[i] + Number(j);
            if (val > target) continue;
            for (var k in sieve[j]) {
                if (sieve[j][k].length < 9) {
                    if (!temp[val]) temp[val] = [];
                    temp[val].push(sieve[j][k].concat([values[i]]));
                }
            }
        }
        for (var j in temp) {
            if (!sieve[j]) sieve[j] = [];
            for (var k in temp[j]) {
                sieve[j].push(temp[j][k].slice());
            }
        }
    }
    return sieve[target];
}

var set = [40,7,112,15,96,25,49,49,31,87,39,8,79,40,73,49,63,55,12,70];
var result = excludedSets(set, 99);
for (var i in result) document.write(result[i] + "<br>");
```

(You'll see a few duplicates in the output, because e.g. the value 49 appears three times in the set.)

Now let's test whether the set without excluded values can be split in two. We see that the sum 99 can be formed e.g. by values 87 and 12, so we exclude these from the set, and get a set of 18 values with the sum 900. Now we check whether the half sum 450 can be formed by adding values from the set:

```js
function sumPossible(values, target) {
    var sieve = [true];
    for (var i in values) {
        var temp = [];
        for (var j in sieve) {
            var val = values[i] + Number(j);
            if (val < target) temp[val] = true;
            else if (val == target) return true;
        }
        for (var j in temp) sieve[j] = temp[j];
    }
    return false;
}
var set = [40,7,112,15,96,25,49,49,31,39,8,79,40,73,49,63,55,70];
document.write(sumPossible(set, 450));
```

So 450 is one of the possible half-sums for this set. Obviously it's not the largest one, because we randomly picked the sum 99 to exclude as an example, instead of iterating over all sums from small to large; in fact the first option, excluding value 7, would have led to the maximum half-sum 496.

It should be noted that the larger the set, the more likely it is that the set can be split in half (if it has an even sum, or with the smallest odd value removed if it has an odd sum). A test with millions of sets of random values with an even sum up to 1000 revealed not a single set that couldn't be split in half, for any set size above 28. (It is of course possible to craft such a set, e.g. 49 ones and a single 51.)

Comment: I think this will work, and I may try to code it later, but obviously Peter's solution is superior :-)

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the array,there are three possibilities.
(i)  Include the element in 1st set
(ii) Include the element in 2nd set
(iii)Does not include the element in any set
whenever sum of first and second set becomes equals update the answer.

```
   public class Main
{
    static int ans = -1;
   public static void find(int[] arr,int sum1,int sum2,int start)
   {    if(sum1==sum2)
         ans = Math.max(ans,sum1);
        if(start==arr.length)
          return;
        find(arr,sum1+arr[start],sum2,start+1);
        find(arr,sum1,sum2+arr[start],start+1);
        find(arr,sum1,sum2,start+1);

   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,100,101,6,100};
       ans = -1;
       find(arr,0,0,0);
       System.out.println(ans);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your approach also.

Answer (score 0):

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

/*
Brute force recursive solve.
*/

void solve(vector&arr, int &ans, int p1, int p2, int idx, int mx_p){

```
// if p1 == p2, we have a potential answer
if(p1 == p2){
    ans = max(ans, p1);
}

//base case 1:
if((p1>mx_p) || (p2>mx_p) || (idx >= arr.size())){
    return;
}

// leave the current element
solve(arr, ans, p1, p2, idx+1, mx_p);

// add the current element to p1
solve(arr, ans, p1+arr[idx], p2, idx+1, mx_p);

// add the current element to p2
solve(arr, ans, p1, p2+arr[idx], idx+1, mx_p);
```

}

/*
Recursive solve with memoization.
*/

int solve(vector<vector<vector>>&memo, vector&arr,
int p1, int p2, int idx, int mx_p){

```
//base case 1:
if((p1>mx_p) || (p2>mx_p) || (idx>arr.size())){
    return -1;
}

// memo'ed answer
if(memo[p1][p2][idx]>-1){
    return memo[p1][p2][idx];
}


// if p1 == p2, we have a potential answer
if(p1 == p2){
    memo[p1][p2][idx] = max(memo[p1][p2][idx], p1);
}

// leave the current element
memo[p1][p2][idx] = max(memo[p1][p2][idx], solve(memo, arr, p1, p2, 
                        idx+1, mx_p));

// add the current element to p1
memo[p1][p2][idx] = max(memo[p1][p2][idx], 
                        solve(memo, arr, p1+arr[idx], p2, idx+1, mx_p));

// add the current element to p2
memo[p1][p2][idx] = max(memo[p1][p2][idx], 
                        solve(memo, arr, p1, p2+arr[idx], idx+1, mx_p));
                        
return memo[p1][p2][idx];
```

}

int main(){

```
vector<int>arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 7};
int ans = 0;
int mx_p = 0;

for(auto i:arr){
    mx_p += i;
}
mx_p /= 2;

vector<vector<vector<int>>>memo(mx_p+1, vector<vector<int>>(mx_p+1, 
                                     vector<int>(arr.size()+1,-1)));
ans = solve(memo, arr, 0, 0, 0, mx_p);
ans = (ans>=0)?ans:0;

// solve(arr, ans, 0, 0, 0, mx_p);
cout << ans << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please improve your nice answer with correct code formatting and a bit more explanation text.